# Unexpected loop when binding property to delegate index via function

Tags: qt, qml

I need to sum the values of foregoing elements in a ListView. Can someone explain me the output? Why will the method be executed three times from the same ListView element? Why does it start again and again from the beginning?

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15

Window {
width: 640
height: 480
visible: true
title: qsTr("Hello World")
ListModel {
    id: fruitModel
    ListElement {name: "Apple";cost: 2}
    ListElement {name: "Orange";cost: 3}
    ListElement {name: "Banana";cost: 4}
}
ListView{
    anchors.fill:parent
    id:listView
    model:fruitModel
    delegate: Item{
        property var myData: model
        width:50
        height:50
        Text{
            text: sum_up(index)
            Component.onCompleted: console.debug("onCompl: "+index)
        }
        function sum_up(foo_index)
        {
            console.debug(foo_index)
            var sum=0;
            for (var i = 0; i <= foo_index; i++)
            {
                sum+=listView.contentItem.children[i].myData.cost
            }
            return sum
}}}}
```

**output:**

```
0
onCompl: 0
0
0
1
onCompl: 1
qrc:/main.qml:33: TypeError: Cannot read property 'cost' of undefined 
0
1
2
onCompl: 2
qrc:/main.qml:33: TypeError: Cannot read property 'cost' of undefined
qrc:/main.qml:33: TypeError: Cannot read property 'cost' of undefined
```

**expected output:**

```
0
onCompl: 0
1
onCompl: 1
2
onCompl: 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's happening is your `sum_up` function is referencing `listView.contentItem.children`. This line:

```
    text: sum_up(index)
```

creates a binding between the text field and the entire list of delegates. So as ListView constructs its children, that binding will continue to be signaled. You can see this is true by removing the reference to `children`:

```
    function sum_up(foo_index)
    {
        console.debug(foo_index)
    }
```

Output:

```
qml: 0
qml: onCompl: 0
qml: 1
qml: onCompl: 1
qml: 2
qml: onCompl: 2
```

Comment: I moved the text binding into delegate onCompleted. This works fine. One thing is left. There are 4 items in contentItem. What is the 4th one?

Comment: It’s up to the ListView implementation what gets added to contentItem. It could be a scrollbar, or the highlight item.